# ReflectionException : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I created a login in Laravel 5.7

the real pass is App\Http\Controllers\siteControllers\Auth
and it was working normally

I write php artisan route: list

and I face this problem

```sh
 ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist
```

and this is my code

to define the file i have created to put the site controller in it

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'siteControllers'], function () { 

    Route::get('/get-login', 'Auth\loginController@view')->name('login-view');  

    Route::post('/check-for-login', 'Auth\loginController@login')>name('check-login'); 
})`
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but don't you have a typo in your `loginController` name? I see you writing it with a capital L and without. Please check that :)

Comment: No, it's working normally put the Route list doesn't appear this is the only problem